# I set the proxy for selenium chrome driver still traffic is going from my local in java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, ip, selenium-chromedriver

I set the proxy to the chrome driver

```
ChromeOptions optionsMap = new ChromeOptions();
        optionsMap.addArguments("--headless");
        optionsMap.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36");
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.MANUAL);
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyValue);
optionsMap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
```

But the traffic is going from local IP address. I want the traffic to go from the proxy. Could you please resolve the issue.
To test I set the chrome driver proxy to different ip not the local address and run the website https://icanhazip.com/ to know the ip. The website still showing the local IP.

I built the chrome driver using the below code

```
String driverAbsPath = new File(seleniumChromeDriverPath).getAbsolutePath().replace("/~/", "/");
ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
   .usingDriverExecutable(new File(driverAbsPath))
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .build();
optionsMap.merge(chromecapabilities);
driver = new ChromeDriver(service, optionsMap);
```

Comment: I THINK what you're trying to do is set a header that sends the targetted ip. Maybe by setting the X-Forwarded-For header?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the ip address into the X-Forwarded-For header on the proxy side:

```
proxy.addHeader("X-Forwarded-For", "1.2.3.4")
```

Comment: I am not having any addHeader method for proxy instance. Can I use 
BrowserMobProxy for adding proxy to the chrome driver?

Comment: I imported org.openqa.selenium.Proxy .

Comment: ah, sorry. I saw proxy and assumed you were using browsermob proxy

Comment: I tried using browsermob it does'nt worked. I am unable to get the website data if I used browsermob proxy.

Comment: How to add username and password for httpproxy, i found only proxy.setSocksUsername,proxy.setSocksPassword . Is there any methods to set user name and password for http proxy.

Comment: documentation at https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy